# Disable-Enable Radio Button According to Server time?

Tags: javascript, html, time, radio-button

I am working on delivery page which has two radio buttons viz.'Regular day time delivery' and 'Require Midnight Delivery'.
I want to display another radio button(viz Same day Delivery) if and only if time is 2 PM and 'Regular day time delivery' is checked Otherwise that button will not be visible or will be disabled.

I can disable button using javascript but don't know how to disable it according to time?

Can anyone Help me?

***Update1:*** I want 'Same day Delivery' button to be visible/enabled after 2PM till 7AM next day.

Update2: I am using PHP-Mysql as Backend/server side Technology

Comment: you should define time span not only a moment 2PM

Comment: You can refer this, http://jsfiddle.net/4fYg7/1/

Comment: why dont you check timestamp while loading the page..accordingly set variable and use condition on it `var d = new Date();
 var n = d.getHours(); `

Comment: `<script>
function disable_button() 
{
 var d = new Date();
   
 var n = d.getHours();
   
 if(n<14)

{

 document.getElementById('button1').disabled=false;
}

else

{
 
document.getElementById('button1').disabled=true;
}

}
</script>`

Comment: `<body onload="disable_button()">` function will get run `onLoad` event of page

Comment: You never specified what server side technology you are using.  You can to do the check on page load(server-side) and enable/disable the buttons or to poll using ajax to check for server-time

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ I am using PHP-mysql as a backend.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143585/check-if-current-time-is-between-two-times-with-the-possibility-of-lapping-days?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction();">

<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" onclick="myFunction();" Value="CC">Regular day time delivery
 <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment" onclick="func2();"  Value="DC">Require Midnight Delivery
 <INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="payment1" id="1" Value="PP" >Same day Delivery
<input type="text" id="h1">
<input type="text" id="h2">

<script>
function myFunction() {
var d = new Date();
var p=Math.floor((d.getTime()/ (1000*60*60)) % 24)
var q=Math.floor((d.getTime()/ (1000*60)) % 60 )
document.getElementById("h1").value=p;
document.getElementById("h2").value=q;

if((p>=1 && q>=30) && ( p<=8 && q<=30) ) 
{
document.getElementById("1").disabled=false;
}
else
{   
document.getElementById("1").disabled=true;
}
}

function func2()
{
document.getElementById("1").checked = false;
document.getElementById("1").disabled=true;

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i used `UTC` time so irrespective of client/country you will get standard time.

Also added textbox to check hours.

You can check code here (copy above code) *As fiddle is not working*
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default

Comment: That is according to the client time though

Comment: it should work,  it's working fine at my end.  as mentioned by E for server side time check this  stackoverflow.com/questions/18281346/how-to-get-server-time-using-javascript due to some emergency it's not possible to edit answer,  will do updation for server time soon

Comment: @NagendraNigade Thank you for updated answer. Unable to try it at the moment as its not considering mine local time. Will check after sometime and will update you. Is it possible to convert UTC to IST? And by the way +1 for answer meanwhile.

Comment: @genius `if(p<14 && p>6)`IST eqivalent to `if(p<8 && p>1)`UTC so change condition with `if(p<8 && p>1)`  will do for enable 6.30am to 13.30pm IST , ya its possible to do it in IST but if this work around is suitable then go for it

Comment: @genius : check now... Any specific reason to convert to IST ??
As this will work perectly fine.

Comment: Thank you @NagendraNigade . Reason is : Website which I am working on is being hosted on server which is located in India.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `setIntertval()` function (checking time every minute):

```
var interv = setInterval(function(){ 
    // from 14 PM till 7 AM
    var hours = (new Date()).getHours();
    if(hours >= 14 || hours < 7) 
        $(".sameDay").hide();
    else
        $(".sameDay").show();
}, 60000);
```

[Here is demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/04r3r62u/)

Comment: That is according to the client time though